# Adding calltips from other files in Komodo Edit

Tags: python, komodo, komodoedit

I'm using Komodo Edit with Python 2.7.11. I want to make it so that Komodo shows calltips for functions that are defined in other files.

There is a solution for this on JavaScript, as I found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/692870/adding-code-completion-to-all-of-my-files-in-komodo-edit), but I couldn't find one for python.

For example:

**apple.py**:

```
def apple():
    """Show that you love apples"""
    print "I love apples!"
```

**apple_caller.py**:

```
execfile("apple.py")
apple(
```

I want the calltip, "Show that you love apples" to be show when I type `apple(` in apple_caller.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Komodo will give you the calltip in your example if you will use `import` instead of `execfile` I doubt it recognizes `execfile` it the same way as `import`.

Comment: Thanks. I shouldn't have been using `execfile` anyway, I just didn't know any better.